# Iterating over a SPARQL query with RDFLib

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib

I have a SPARQL query that retrieves all the nodes linked to the classes in an ontology of the human anatomy:

```
queryloop=graph.query("""SELECT ?node ?othernodes ?othernodesLabel WHERE { 
?node rdf:type owl:Class .
?node ?y ?othernodes .
?othernodes rdfs:label ?othernodesLabel
} 
LIMIT 100""")
```

I now need to iterate over the results and group the labels in a python dictionary, so that the key contains the label of the class (`?node`), and the value contains the labels of the adjoining nodes, so that for every class in the ontology there is a dictionary key (and for each key there are as many values as adjoining classes). I don't know how variable bindings work in rdflib so I don't know how to write a for-loop in python that would have access to the SPARQL query.

Comment: I already showed you the link to the documentation where you can find an example and also other links to the Python API: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html

Comment: I know, I've read the documentation several times and can't make sense of it. I tried doing this                                                                                        dictlabels={}
for x in queryloop:
    dictlabels.update({"""%s:?othernodes rdfs:label othernodesLabel"""}%x)                                                                                            but I get an 'unsupported operand type' error.

Comment: That leads me to the conclusion that you did not read the documentation carefully...the sentence *"Alternatively, the values can be accessed by variable name, either as attributes, or as items: row.b and row["b"] is equivalent."* exactly declares how to access the values of each row.

Comment: I missed that, thank you for your patience.

Comment: If you have the solution, please provide it as an answer and also accept it. This will help others having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As AKSW pointed out, the easiest way to do this would be to include whatever elements you want to transfer to the dictionary in the SPARQL query, and then access them as attributes before appending them to the dictionary like so:

```
queryloop=graph.query("""SELECT ?node ?nodelabel ?othernodes ?othernodesLabel     WHERE { 
?node rdf:type owl:Class .
?node ?y ?othernodes .
?othernodes rdfs:label ?othernodesLabel
?node rdfs:label ?nodeLabel
} 
LIMIT 100""")

dictlabels={}
for row in queryloop:
    dictlabels.update(row.node, row.nodeLabel: row.othernodes,row.othernodesLabel)
```

This way you have the node and its label as the key, and all the adjoining nodes and their labels as the values.